# Split binary file

Tags: java, io, binaryfiles

The split method takes two arguments, name of file to split, and size of each split. Could you check if I'm on the write track? And the pseudocode on what to put in the for loop?

```
import java.io.*;

public class SplitFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Split("testfile.pdf", 256);

    }

    public static Split(String filename, int splitSize) throws IOException {

        int numberOfFiles = 0;

        File file = new File(filename);

        numberOfFiles = ((int) file.length() / splitSize) + 1;

        for (; numberOfFiles >= 0; numberOfFiles--) {

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(filename)));

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))); //What do I put here?

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to explain what you're looking for: file naming patterns? the code to open a new output stream? or what? Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: @NathanTuggy Well for starters I don't know if I'm on the right track. I just put together some code I found on this site. Java IO has so many classes! And I'm stuck on how to proceed. Pseudocode will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required changes

- File object per output part, e.g.
- Initialize data input stream outside the loop, not inside

Code

```
File original = new File(filename);
int numberOfFiles = ((int) original.length() / splitSize) + 1;

DataInputStream in = 
    new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));

// <== just count through parts.
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
    File output = new File(String.format("%s-%d", filename, i));
    // <== Part of file being output e.g. testfile.pdf-1, testfile.pdf-2

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)));

}
```

For the actual writing...

- read bytes from input stream using read() call
- write bytes to output stream using write() call

Two approaches, either 1 byte at a time - easiest, but less efficient, or use a buffer, harder to code, but more efficient.

Buffered approach

```
long length = original.length();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));

int pos = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[splitSize];
for (...) {
    ...

    // make sure you deal with file not being exactly divisible, 
    // last chunk might be smaller
    long remaining = length - pos;
    in.read(buffer, pos, (int) Math.min(splitSize, remaining));
    out.write(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(splitSize, remaining));

    pos += splitSize;
}
```

1 byte at a time.

```
for (...) {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < splitSize && pos < length; i++) {
        out.write(in.read());
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the Java NIO API in the following way.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public final class SplitFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        split("testfile.pdf", 256);
    }

    private static void split(String filename, int splitSize) throws IOException {
        int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        String basename = filename.substring(0, i);
        String ext = filename.substring(i + 1);

        Path inputPath = Paths.get(filename);

        int numberOfFiles = (int) (Files.size(inputPath) / splitSize) + 1;

        try (FileChannel inputChannel = FileChannel.open(inputPath, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFiles; j++) {
                String outputFilename = String.format("%s-%04d.%s", basename, j + 1, ext);

                Path outputPath = inputPath.getParent().resolve(outputFilename);

                try (FileChannel outputChannel = FileChannel.open(outputPath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
                    inputChannel.transferTo(j * splitSize, splitSize, outputChannel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we merge the files back?